# Error in mPDF Xref?

Tags: php, pdf, yii

I am using the mpdf extension in my yii2 site in which the pdf are created.The pdf files are uploaded as an attachment first & then merged using the mpdf, this is working fine for the pdf files of version less than or equals to 1.4 & if i use a pdf file greater than this it gives me the error.I found the posts regarding this too but there is no actual answer its just asked to use the FPDI which also causes this error & i cannot chang my library to any other my whole work is dependent on this mpdf library.The users cannot save there file firstly in lower version & then upload it so please suggest me something i can do with it.

```
        //merge multiple PDF files
                    $pdf=new mPDF('', 'Letter', 0, '', 8.5, 11);
                    $pdf->SetImportUse();
                    if($body !="")
                    {
                    $pdf->WriteHTML($body);
                    $pdf->WriteHTML('<pagebreak />');
                    }
                    $body1='<style>@page {margin: 96px;border:1px solid red;}</style>';
                    $fileArcount =  count($multifileArr);   
                    $z=1;
                    foreach($multifileArr as $fileAr)
                    {                           

                    if($fileAr !="")
                    {
                        $dashboard_pdf_file="../web/uploads/".$fileAr;
                    }
                    $pagecount = $pdf->SetSourceFile($dashboard_pdf_file);

                    for ($i=1; $i<=$pagecount; $i++) {
                        $import_page = $pdf->ImportPage($i);
                        $pdf->UseTemplate($import_page);

                        if ($i < $pagecount)
                        {

                            //$pdf->AddPage();

                            $pdf->AddPage('L',80,80,80);
                        }

                    }
                    if($z < $fileArcount){
                    $pdf->WriteHTML('<pagebreak />');
                    }
                    $z++;
                    }
```

Comment: I haven't used yii2 yet, I have used yii1 and im a newbie, What i did with mpdf in my website, I have many users on my website, Through i admin I can view any user profile and all of info is saved on profile page, I have added a button when an admin click on that button to generate pdf, it will create pdf of that yii view page and save on servers and then download that file.

Comment: Thanks for replying ! I am getting this issue while merging multiple PDF's files & creating a new one, when a pdf file is parsed it reads out the verion of PDF fiel in which it is made & works fine for version lower than 1.4 but having issue for higher versions.

Comment: I think it is possible, I have done similar to this one.. I have many users on my website, Every user has uploaded multiple files zip files, doc files, excel sheets etc..  I have a folder uploads/1 for user id 1 and uploads/2 for user 2.. similarly for all users, All of their uploads files are saved in their folder in uploads. Then my client requested to download all the files in zip, Im getting all files of each user and downloading in zip.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I think you took me wrong i am getting issue because of pdf version uploded 'mPDF error: Unable to find xref table - Maybe a Problem with 'auto_detect_line_endings'', this occurs while pdf file is parsed .